# Checking for required M4 macros... yelp.m4 not found

Tags: compiling, macro, m4

I am on Linux Mint 18 Cinnamon 64-bit.

I was about to compile `file-roller` known as [Archive manager for GNOME from source](https://github.com/GNOME/file-roller).

But when running:

```
./autogen.sh
```

There is a following M4 macro missing:

> ```
> Checking for required M4 macros...
> yelp.m4 not found
> ***Error***: some autoconf macros required to build Package
> were not found in your aclocal path, or some forbidden
> macros were found.  Perhaps you need to adjust your
> ACLOCAL_PATH?
> ```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`apt-file`](https://tracker.debian.org/apt-file) for this, without necessarily knowing where the M4 files go:

```
apt-file search yelp.m4
```

will tell you where the particular file should be located even without having the package (`yelp-tools`) installed.

```
yelp-tools: /usr/share/aclocal/yelp.m4
```

This tells you that installing `yelp-tools` should allow the build to proceed further.

Alternatively, you can check [the build-dependencies of `file-roller` in Debian](https://packages.debian.org/source/unstable/file-roller): that lists `yelp-tools` too, along with all the other packages you’ll need.

On Linux Mint 18 [`apt-file`](https://tracker.debian.org/apt-file) isn’t pre-installed, but it’s easy to install:

```
sudo apt-get install apt-file
```

After installation you will need to update its database with:

```
sudo apt-file update
```

Answer (score 3):

First, I must have figured out where the macros are located:

```
aclocal --print-ac-dir
```

Attribution for this line [goes here](https://askubuntu.com/a/673660/436624).

In my case it is:

```
/usr/share/aclocal
```

Searching for such file there gave no result:

```
ls /usr/share/aclocal | grep yelp
```

So the hunt begins:

```
apt-cache policy yelp*
```

There are 3 packaged, two of them were already installed, so I installed the missing one:

```
sudo apt-get install yelp-tools
```

Repeating my search:

```
ls /usr/share/aclocal | grep yelp
```

Gave a result:

```
yelp.m4
```

Problem solved.